# "Page not found" on translated page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, i18n-l10n

I’m setting up a dual language site (English default / Chinese, Simplified) where Taxonomy translation mode is “Localize”.

I modified the Taxonomy term in Views.

I get results with preview in both default and translated language.

In page views, English is okay. However, Chinese page return “Page not found”.

I have tried Content: Has taxonomy term ID (translated) & Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth, translated) and a different validator "Taxonomy term (i18n)".

What did I missed? Please enlighten.

Comment: r u using i18n module?

Comment: yes, I am. i18n, i18n views, taxonomy translation. Drupal 7.

Comment: Try this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/63343/7177

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a chinese alias for your view page ?
Eg.: your view has an alias set to "my-listing" for the "EN" language.
=> Try to set a chinese alias corresponding to "my-listing" alias, but for chinese...

Comment: I didn't because it's already been handled by i18n views. No? My http://example.com/tags/abc shows my nodes. http://example.com/zh-hans/tags/abc shows "Page not found". Alternatively, I'll have to create /tags/abc alias to zh-hans/tags/abc. Having a long list of terms, this may not be feasible. I don't think pathauto can accept wildcard.