# overriden term name not translated on a taxonomy overriden views page

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Title module with Entity translation to translate my taxonomy terms.
I have overridden my term page with a view with term id as contextual filter.
In the contextual filter section, I'm overriding the title view page with the contextual filter %1.
I'm validating the contextual filter by checking if it's a term id.

Unfortunately the title page is not translated. In my case term name displayed is always the one in English.

Just to test further, if I'm adding 2 fields term name and term description to my views. The 2 fields are correctly translated, by switching languages.

Comment: There's some preliminary code for this in the [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2378991), in the Entity Translation issue queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Internationalization Views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module.

then select this,
Advanced > Contextual filters > Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" > select the validator "Taxonomy term (i18n)"

[See here](http://drupal.org/files/issue-1541924-views-validataion-criteria.jpg)

Comment: I think this will only work if you're using [Interationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), not [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) for translating terms.